# Looking for where in the linux 2.6.33.20 kernel source SCSI timeouts are created/set up

Tags: linux, kernel, scsi

In older versions of the kernel (2.6.25.8), it was in drivers/scsi/scsi_error.c in the functions scsi_add_timer and scsi_delete_timer: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/scsi/scsi_error.c?v=2.6.25.8

I can't seem to find anything similar in scsi_error.c in the 2.6.33.20 kernel, I've looked in other files (using grep and searching for time) and see mentions of timeouts, but nothing that looks similar like where you're setting the timeout value for the timer.

Any help is greatly appreciated, been banging my head on this for a while.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that what you're trying to find was changed in [`242f9dcb8ba6f68fcd217a119a7648a4f69290e9`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=patch;h=242f9dcb8ba6f68fcd217a119a7648a4f69290e9), when the timeouts were lifted out of the specific block devices and moved into the block device abstraction layer.

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you have any tips on how I can find this stuff in the future? I'm going to be mucking around in the kernel a lot.

Comment: For this specific one, I read the `git log` for the specific file you had and searched for `time` or `timer` or something like that. One patch was fixing incorrect braces introduced with that patch, and the changelog entry for that patch looked _perfect_. I got a bit lucky that the big change was clearly labeled in the log, but I probably would have found it eventually anyhow.

Comment: Were you using this website or the actual git repository? http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=summary

Comment: I was using a cloned `git` repository on my local machine; I included the link because it is far easier for casual browsing (you or other future visitors) but I would not rely solely on it for research work -- the latency is far too high between operations.

Comment: I just cloned the repo and it was really easy to find the change. Thanks.

Comment: Hating the kernel so much, haha. I keep looking and it seems like the really obfuscated all the timeout code with this commit.  Can't find where the actual timeouts are dealt with similar to the scsi_add_timer and delete timer before

Comment: In `block/blk-timeout.c` there's `blk_add_timer()` and `blk_delete_timer()`, along with some helpful utilities. If you're migrating a specific patch, you might wish to try to re-implement the patch in the new system rather than try to _port_ the patch over.. (It's a very subtle difference of attitude more than anything else, but you might find it helpful all the same. I know I have..)